# JQ to Parse JSON Response

Tags: json, parsing, jq

I've tried a ton of combos on this handy tool here:
https://jqplay.org
But I can't seem to get the piece I need. Here's my JSON:

```
{
  "data": {
    "translations": [
      {
        "translatedText": "El rápido zorro marrón saltó sobre el perro perezoso."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get just this part "El rápido zorro marrón saltó sobre el perro perezoso." without quotes.

The closest I got was with this:

```
.data.translations
```

(but this fails to get what I'm looking for) Any help would be great, thanks.

I got flagged for a duplicate question, but this isn't using Javascript.

Comment: `.data.translations[0].translatedText` and make sure you check the `Raw Output` checkbox (translates to the `--raw-output` or `-r` flags if using in the command line).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: @JJJ, no... jq isn't javascript.

Comment: @Gavin thanks! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider also:

```
$ jq -r '.data.translations[].translatedText' input.json
El rápido zorro marrón saltó sobre el perro perezoso.
```

or even:

```
jq -r '.data.translations[][]' input.json
El rápido zorro marrón saltó sobre el perro perezoso.
```

Which is appropriate will of course depend on the detailed requirements.